# TCP_DEFER_ACCEPT behavior for keep-alive connections?

Tags: sockets, http, networking, tcp

As I understand it, TCP_DEFER_ACCEPT (or, for BSD, the accept filter of httpready) will cause the kernel to delay notifying the application of a pending connection until an entire http message is ready.

My question relates to persistent (i.e., keep-alive) connections, which can have multiple HTTP requests sent.  Will the kernel buffer each one, or only the initial one?  If not, is there a way to set things up that gets around me having to create a buffer for each connection in application space?

Answer (score 1):

> (or, for BSD, the accept filter of httpready) will cause the kernel to delay notifying the application of a pending connection until an entire http message is ready

No. It defers completion of `accept()` 'until data arrives'.

TCP doesn't know what a complete HTTP request is.

Your question doesn't make sense in any case. Once a connection is accepted it's accepted. Arrival of a second request can't change that.

Comment: I was confusing the "httpready" filter that FreeBSD has with deferred accept.  Apparently Linux doesn't have this capability.  Thanks for the comments.